# Combine two JSON then add title

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have two JSON objects and I'm planning to join them.

```
obj1 = [{'foo': 'bar', 'foo1': 'bar1'}];
obj2 = [{'foo2': 'bar2'}];

objFinal = [
  {
    "foo": "bar", 
    "foo1": "bar1",
    "title": 
    [
      { "foo2": "bar2" }
    ] 
  }
]
```

My plan is to get the result the same as objFinal. I've used `.concat` but it didn't returned the result I wanted. What are other options I can do to get the result as same as `objFinal`?

Comment: There is no such thing as "JSON objects". They're just objects once you parse them from a JSON string, specifically, arrays. "I've used `.concat` but it didn't returned the result I wanted" -- please show this code as an edit to your post.

Comment: `let objFinal=[{...obj1[0], title:[{...obj2[0]}]}];`

Comment: You don't actually want to combine two objects; you want one array to be added to the other object as a property. Search on that, without mentioning JSON (as ggorlen is correct; this has nothing to do with JSON), and perhaps you'll find the answer.  There are other unanswered questions which make [the current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68792779/215552) and @tevemadar's comment unfit. For instance, what happens if there is more than one object in either array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
objFinal = [{ ...obj1[0], title: obj2}];
```